# Setting python path programmatic

Tags: python, python-import

**Aim:-**

I would want to set python path programmatic in my project. So that, all other directories files can be imported without any issues.

**Problem statement:-**

I used to add all the folders & sub-folders in environment variables under **PYTHONPATH** but this has two constrains.

1, Any new folders created need to be added in environment variables all the times. After certain limit, environment variables will not be accepted new path reference due to characters limitaion.

***- Error: This environment variable is too large. This dialog allows
   setting values up to 2047 characters long.***

2, Secondly, all the team members in my team need to perform the same activity manually all the times.

**Tried self solution:-**

Created a sample folder and added the below code before main import files and ran from command prompt which worked perfectly fine.

```
**FilePath: foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory1/File1.py**

class File1():

    def parent(self):
        return "I am from File1"

**FilePath: foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory2/File2.py**

    import sys
try:
    sys.path.index('foo/Python/Learning&Development')
    sys.path.index('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice')
    sys.path.index('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory1')
    sys.path.index('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory2')
except ValueError:
    sys.path.append('foo/Python/Learning&Development')
    sys.path.append('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice')
    sys.path.append('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory1')
    sys.path.append('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory2')

from Pratice.Directory1.File1 import File1 as f


class File2():

    def child(self):
        return f.parent(self)
```

Results:

[image]

Now I wish to convert the sys.path as a single method and call automatically before running any .py file in the project folder.

So, on trail basis, I created '**init**.py' file added the same piece (sys.path) of code, commented the same code in File2.py and run it but ended up with file import error.

```
**FilePath: foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory2/__init__.py**

import sys
try:
    sys.path.index('foo/Automation/Python/Learning&Development')
    sys.path.index('foo/Automation/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice')
    sys.path.index('foo/Automation/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory1')
    sys.path.index('foo/Automation/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory2')
except ValueError:
    sys.path.append('foo/Automation/Python/Learning&Development')
    sys.path.append('foo/Automation/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice')
```

sys.path.append('foo/Automation/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory1')
    sys.path.append('foo/Automation/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory2')

```
**FilePath: foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory1/File1.py**

class File1():

    def parent(self):
        return "I am from File1"

**FilePath: foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory2/File2.py**

# import sys
# try:
    # sys.path.index('foo/Python/Learning&Development')
    # sys.path.index('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice')
    # sys.path.index('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory1')
    # sys.path.index('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory2')
# except ValueError:
    # sys.path.append('foo/Python/Learning&Development')
    # sys.path.append('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice')
    # sys.path.append('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory1')
    # sys.path.append('foo/Python/Learning&Development/Pratice/Directory2')

from Pratice.Directory1.File1 import File1 as f


class File2():

    def child(self):
        return f.parent(self)
```

[image]

Could someone help me on this problem? I would want the same piece of code to be executed before running any of the .py file in my project folder. So that, import error would not come into picture.

Expected: Python path should be set automatically by default and import error should not occur while running any python file in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue resolved by adding the top most folder in environment variables and setting this up as source root in pycharm. Also, have import the files from source root in respective folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

solution is to sets default python path that run every python file. you don't need to add file to environment variable when new file or folder is added.
just simply configure your environment variable e-g in my system windows i add `C:\Anaconda\python.exe` you just add path to environment variable where your `python.exe` file is located.

Comment: Issue exists even after adding the path where python.exe lies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file **init**.py in every directory. (2 leading underscores and two trailing underscores.)
The you only need to include the top directory to you sys.path and can import stuff from subdirectories using 
topdir.subdir

Comment: Should I add the top directory in system environment variables or sys.path in every python file? Please clarify.

Comment: That depends on your use case. If you want to use it for your own, setting an environment variable is fine. But if you want to share it with other or deploy to customers, that wouldn't be good.